# Javascript: Linq.js: return Array

Tags: javascript, linq

I'm new to Linq.js and am trying to get a subset of a json string.
My Json string is as follows:
eventJSON:

```
[{"EventID": "1", "Description": "Hello World", "EventTime": "16123456000"}, 
{"EventID": "2", "Description": "Carpe Diem", "EventTime": "16123656000"}, 
{"EventID": "3", "Description": "Desc3", "EventTime": "16123656000"}]
```

I have a function that iterates through this json and tries to return a subset based on the eventtime value. THe code is as follows:

```
videoPlayer.on('playtime', function (pts) {
    var pts = 16123656000;

    if (eventJSON != null) {
        var _resultArray = Enumerable.From(eventJSON).Select(function (eventrecord) { return Number(eventrecord.EventTime) == Number(pts); }).ToArray();
        if (_resultArray.length > 0) {
            _resultArray.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
                console.log(item.EventTime);
            }
            )                
        }                
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to be working. How do I get a subset of the json as an array and iterate through them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `linq.js` for this. Just use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
let data = [{"EventID": "1", "Description": "Hello World", "EventTime": "16123456000"}, 
{"EventID": "2", "Description": "Carpe Diem", "EventTime": "16123656000"}, 
{"EventID": "3", "Description": "Desc3", "EventTime": "16123656000"}];

let pts = 16123656000;

let filtered = data
  .filter(x => +x.EventTime === pts);
filtered.forEach(x => console.log(x.EventTime));
```

For your second requirement you can make use of [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
//find latest with <= pts Variant 1
//sort descending and find the first element that meets the condition
let latest = data
  .sort((a,b) => +b.EventTime - +a.EventTime)
  .find(x => +x.EventTime <= pts)

//Variant 2
//filter all elements meeting the condition, sort descending 
//and take the first element
let latest = data
  .filter(x => +x.EventTime <= pts)
  .sort((a,b) => +b.EventTime - +a.EventTime)[0]

//Variant 3
//using reduce and search for the maximum meeting the condition
let latest = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (+c.EventTime > pts) return a;
  if (!a) return c;
  return +a.EventTime > +c.EventTime ? a : c;
  }, undefined);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out and it works.

Comment: How do I get the max EventTime value from the filtered where x.EventTime <= pts?